# searching pattern in a string

Tags: c++, recursion

I am really having a hard time getting recursions but i tried recursion to match a pattern inside a string.

Suppose i have a string **geeks for geeks** and i have a pattern **eks** to match.I could use many methods out there like **regex**, **find** method of string class but i really want to do this thing by recursions.

To achieve this i tried this code:

```
void recursion(int i,string str)
{
    if(!str.compare("eks"))
        cout<<"pattern at :"<<i<<'\n';

    if(i<str.length() && str.length()-1!=0)
        recursion(i,str.substr(i,str.length()-1));
}

int main()
{
    string str("geeks for geeks");

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        recursion(i,str.substr(i,str.length()));
}
```

Output :

[image]

Desired Ouput :

```
pattern at 2
pattern at 12
```

What could i be doing wrong here and what would be a good way to do this with recursions?

I understood a lot of topics in cpp but with recursions , i know how they work and even with that whenever i try to code something with recursions , it never works.Could there be any place that could help me with recursions as well?

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger, if you haven't done it before. With a debugger you can step through your code line by line to see what's happening. And also step into function calls to follow them. All the while you can monitor variables and their values.

Comment: What is your desired output? After all, your program returns 0.

Comment: @Zeta desired ouput would be the location of the pattern , suppose for above it should be `pattern at 2` `pattern at 12` .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, is there a link to learn debugger?

Comment: why do you have loop before calling the function? and won't you need to have i++ inside the function?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo loop would loop all elements one by one.Suppose, for the first position `geeks for geeks ` is passed and then recursion is done on this string, similarly on second pass `eeks for geeks ` is passed and so on.

Comment: @BOTJr. add std::cout << str << std::endl; inside recursion and you will understand the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never get `pattern at 2`, since `compare` doesn't work like that. Ask yourself, what will

```
std::string("eks for geeks").compare("eks")
```

return? Well, according to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare), you will get something positive, since `"eks for geeks"` is longer than `"eks"`. So your first step is to fix this:

```
void recursion(int i, std::string str){
  if(!str.substr(0,3).compare("eks")) {
    std::cout << "pattern at: " << i << '\n';
  }
```

Next, we have to recurse. But there's something off. `i` should be the current position of your "cursor". Therefore, you should advance it:

```
  i = i + 1;
```

And if we reduce the length of the string in every iteration, we must not test `i < str.length`, otherwise we won't check the later half of the string:

```
  if(str.length() - 1 > 0) {
    recursion(i, str.substr(1));
  }
}
```

Before we actually compile this code, let's reason about it:

- we have a substring of the correct length for comparison with `"eks"`
- we never use `i` except for the current position
- we advance the position before we recurse
- we "advance" the string by removing the first character
- we will end up with an empty string at some point

Seems reasonable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void recursion(int i, std::string str){
  if(!str.substr(0,3).compare("eks")) {
    std::cout << "pattern at: " << i << '\n';
  }

  i = i + 1;

  if(str.length() - 1 > 0) {
    recursion(i, str.substr(1));
  }
}

int main () {
    recursion(0, "geeks for geeks");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pattern at: 2
pattern at: 12
```

However, that's not optimal. There are several optimizations that are possible. But that's left as an exercise.

## Exercises

1. `compare` needs to use `substr` due to it's algorithm. Write your own comparison function that doesn't need `substr`.
2. There's a lot of copying going on. Can you get rid of that?
3. The `for` loop was wrong. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function must not run into loop. And you have some mistakes.Try this code.

```
void recursion(string str, string subStr, int i){
    if(str.find(subStr) != string::npos ) {
        int pos = str.find(subStr);
        str = str.substr(pos + subStr.length(), str.length()-1);
        cout << "pattern at " << (pos + i) << endl;
        recursion(str, subStr, pos+subStr.length() );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string str("geeks for geeks");
    string subStr("eks");
    recursion(str, subStr, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will upvote this answer if you back up your answer with something as to why we should not use recursions in loops ?

Comment: In terms of loop variants, structural recursion is when there is an obvious loop variant, namely size or complexity, which starts off finite and decreases at each recursive step.
By contrast, generative recursion is when there is not such an obvious loop variant, and termination depends on a function, such as "error of approximation" that does not necessarily decrease to zero, and thus termination is not guaranteed without further analysis.

Comment: read more about Recursion (computer science). And it is not ethical "I will upvote this answer if you..." My answer correctly is solving your problem.      You might wrote thanks

Comment: It wasn't unethical, answers without any backed sources are not good.A good answer is the one that has things backed with some sources.It makes the answer complete. :)